# How to send duble variable into one database(table) field?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In the first variable I store the name of a picture. The second one stores the path to this picture. The MySQL field should get both of them in order so I can access it from browser. How can I do this? I've already tried this:

```
$path = 'www.something.com/images/';
$sql = "INSERT INTO tb_user_info " . "(user_image)"."VALUES( '$path'.'$user_pic')";
```

Comment: It is unclear what you ask. Mixing two separate values ("variables") into a single one is not a good idea, you loose information. You certainly _could_ concatenate those two values (strings) to a single one to store them inside one table cell, but _why_? Why don't you use _two_ cells in a row, which is much more convenient, since that way you can retrieve both values independent from each other?

Comment: Because I get the name of the picture from a form, and I need the full path to access the picture, not just the name. That's why i tried to link the two string, cause separately they aren't useable.

Comment: I'd say they are only usable _if_ they are separate. If you somehow mix them, then how do you want to use them? For example the path? You will have to separate them again.

Comment: Why don't you simply explain what you are trying to do so that we can help  instead of trying to explain how you think you might be able to get it done?

Comment: I'm going to convert into json, and an android device will query it. I thought  it's the best way to do it. Can you offer any alternative?

Comment: You certainly can do that. The obvious ans cleaner alternative would be to have two separate cells or columns as I said before. You have to somehow wrap the data anyway to send it as a reply to an API request. However _if_ you _really_ want to combine those two values as a JSON string, then what is your question? Then you have a single string. You can store that in your table cell.

Comment: Can you explain how can I do it? I'm a rookie...

Comment: How to do what? To combine two strings into a JSON formatted string? Well, just take a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php So do something like `json_encode([$path, $user_pic]);`

Comment: Thx for the help  :)

Comment: But as said: it is better to store the values separate. Then, during the API request you retrieve the full row from the database. That gives you an associative array holding all columns which you can then for example json encode to hand it over as a response. That allows to have a clean database model which you can also use for other clients.

Comment: It's gonna work, thanks for the guidance!

Answer (score -1):

Well first of all, you should be using prepared statements with `mysqli` or `pdo`. But to answer your question.

```
  $path = 'www.something.com/images/' . $user_pic;
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tb_user_info (user_image) VALUES( '$path')";
```

Comment: What didn't work?  It updated the database but not correctly or what?